# how to put android on low power state

Tags: android, power-management

i have a highly data computation intensive application that has to process data received via bluetooth every 60 seconds and then stay in low power state for the next 60 seconds. i checked out the PowerManager api but i am unable to use it. is there a way i could accomplish the task?

Comment: Why are you unable to use PowerManager?

Comment: @MisterSquonk...it says permission not granted...maybe because its a system api and it cannot be accessed by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "put android on low power state". Android naturally will go into a sleep mode after a period of inactivity, if nothing is holding a `WakeLock` to force the CPU to stay running.

Comment: can we alter the period of inactivity? I read in one the post answered by Mark Murphy that we can create an application sign it using our own firmware..is that a possibility?

Comment: @raqz: "can we alter the period of inactivity?" -- it looks like `SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT` in `Settings.System` may let you change this, but I have not tried it. "I read in one the post answered by Mark Murphy that we can create an application sign it using our own firmware..is that a possibility?" -- you can certainly create your own firmware, and you presumably have lower-level power control that way, such as `goToSleep()`, but, again, I haven't tried it.

Comment: @CommonsWare..atleast could you please guide me or let me know if you have seen anybody doing that..thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare...create an application and sign it using my own firmware..i googled for it but dint find anything worth while...

Comment: @raqz: http://source.android.com is the home for all firmware-related stuff, including some Google Groups that may be of relevance to you. Also, trying to ask questions about firmware and signing on a "put android on low power state" question will not get you far -- open up a fresh question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerManager goToSleep() method to "force the device to go to sleep. Overrides all the wake locks that are held": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29